# jQuery tool  plugging for dynamic controls

Tags: asp.net, jquery

in my application  i  creating a    dynamic  controls  like ( 2 label  controls  in  2 tds  of   under  1  tr  of  a  table   doing  this in .cs  file). 
now  i need  to   provide   the  tool tip  for these   dynamic  controls   what i have    generated

can  any one  help me  out  to  give  solution for this

thank  you

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you only looking for a tooltip plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google search for jquery and tooltip gave me this: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

Comment: JQuery  Plugin  helps  do  it